# Docker- django throws error while connecting to postgres: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I am trying to dockerize my Django-postgres app.
My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

and my settings .py has the following database code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

My db and web containers are up but when I run: 
**docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate**
I am getting the error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>           Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How can I make my containers communicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change `HOST` to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

`0.0.0.0` is not a valid `IP`, beside you need to connect using the `service` name since `compose` will resolve it for you

Comment: Can I use the service name in my python code if I want to connect to db? It worked in the scenario above but failed in other places.

Comment: when I run: 
`con = psycopg2.connect("host=db dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password")`

I got the error:

**could not translate host name "db" to address: Unknown host**

Comment: if that runs in one of the two containers from the compose , then yes that should work.

Comment: It worked when I ran it from the container. Thanks a lot @LinPy !

Comment: if you want to use that outside the container just use : `localhost:5432`

Comment: I want to use my Django app outside the container and I can't access it using: `localhost:5432/api/`
That doesn't seem to work for some reason. `netstat -ant | find "8000"` and `netstat -ant | find "5432"` are both empty

Comment: but is that right that you called the api from your `db` container ? isnt it `localhost:8000/api/...`?

Comment: Yes that is right. But I want to access it outside the container too. `localhost:8000/api/…` is what it should be. But it isn't working.