# Docker-compose on a django app postgresql connection refuse

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

i try to dockerize my django app,
here my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    networks:
      - mynetwork

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

inside my django app, in my settings.py i have this parameters for db connection:
settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydbname',
        'USER': 'mydbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mydbpassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
    }
}
```

well at this point when i run

```
docker-compose build
```

al was done, but when i do:

```
docker-compose up
```

i get this error:

> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>   web_1       | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   web_1       |   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>   web_1       |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

how can i manage my django db connection parameters using my docker postgres image?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: This site should help with the walkthrough: https://wsvincent.com/django-docker-postgresql/

Comment: change `host` to `postgres` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker- django throws error while connecting to postgres: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073985/docker-django-throws-error-while-connecting-to-postgres-psycopg2-operationaler)

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose, you can take advantage of docker-compose networking. You can do service to service communication base on container name.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydbname',
        'USER': 'mydbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mydbpassword',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
    }
}
```

In the connection when you used `127.0.0.1` it refere to the localhost of web-app not the postgress which is also mentioend in comment by @Michalk.

Comment: thanks, if i try with postgres i get: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve

Comment: @ManuelSanti Run `docker ps` and confirm if `postgres` service is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `host` of your database settings to `postgres` as this is the service name in your `docker-compose`. Internally docker-compose will create a network and attach containers to it. Service names defined in docker-compose will be DNS names mapped to container IPs :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydbname',
        'USER': 'mydbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mydbpassword',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) will not make sure database is initialized fully before app container tries to reach it. This is also documented in the link that I shared :

> `depends_on` does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve