# Azure Pipelines on Django app: Psycopg2 fails to initialize for unit tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure-pipelines, psycopg2

I'm having issues setting up a small pipeline for my Django app.

Here's the `yaml` configuration:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python39:
      PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9'
  maxParallel: 2

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(PYTHON_VERSION)'
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: dotEnv
  inputs:
    secureFile: '.env'

- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Export project path'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      """Search all subdirectories for `manage.py`."""
      from glob import iglob
      from os import path
      # Python >= 3.5
      manage_py = next(iglob(path.join('**', 'manage.py'), recursive=True), None)
      if not manage_py:
          raise SystemExit('Could not find a Django project')
      project_location = path.dirname(path.abspath(manage_py))
      print('Found Django project in', project_location)
      print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectRoot]{}'.format(project_location))

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Add .env file'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: '.env'
    TargetFolder: '$(projectRoot)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel pipenv
    pipenv install unittest-xml-reporting
  displayName: 'Install prerequisites'

- script: python -m pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Create requirements.txt from Pipfile'

- script: pipenv install
  displayName: 'Install requirements'

- script: |
    pushd '$(projectRoot)'
    pipenv run python manage.py test --testrunner xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner --no-input
  displayName: 'Run tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: "**/TEST-*.xml"
    testRunTitle: 'Python $(PYTHON_VERSION)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The problem happens when the `Run tests` script starts as Django can't create a test database, but the error message seems quite generic:

```sh
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Should I be adding steps to create a PostgreSQL database?

Is it possible to run with a lighter solution.. but without creating another settings.py module just for CI (which doesn't seem ideal)?

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME", ""),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER", ""),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASS", ""),
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074004/11508192), try to change `HOST` .

Comment: The last comment days that, if I want to use that outside a container, I should just use localhost:5432, which is as my code currently is.